# add leading zeros in numbers

Tags: format

I want to show my column data like
001,
002,
..
..
00100,
00101
..

my column name is Srno and datatype is int
 how can i show my column data like this format in sql

Comment: What environment?  What language?  What context?

Comment: Question should be more exact or closed!

Comment: @reuben I am using MsSqlServer 2008 r2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,srno),6) FROM table
```

Comment: can you post a picture/layout of the possible output

Comment: do you need to do this from the back-end?

Comment: 1,
2,
3,
..
........
99,
100,
101,
102, it is my present output i want to show column data like 001,002,.......00100,00101,00102.........001000,001001

Comment: SELECT RIGHT('00' + CAST([SaleOrder.SrNo] AS varchar(250)) , 8)
FROM SaleOrder............but its not working

Comment: try this:  SELECT RIGHT('00' + CONVERT([SaleOrder.SrNo] AS VARCHAR) , 8) FROM SaleOrder

Comment: but....when i am trying SELECT RIGHT('00' + CONVERT([SaleOrder.SrNo] AS VARCHAR) , 8) FROM SaleOrder.........it is not working but when i am trying SELECT RIGHT('00' + CONVERT([SrNo] AS VARCHAR) , 8) FROM SaleOrder it is working ....and i need SrnO as Saleorder.Srno......

Comment: it should SaleOrder.[SrNo] or SaleOrder.SrNo NOT [SaleOrder.Srno]